# How to do I retrieve a particular XML element based on its child elements in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my XML Document (small snippet).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

<w:body>
    <w:p> <!-- Current Node -->
        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 This is the
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:pict>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>
                            I dont need this
                        </w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:pict>
        </w:r>

        <w:r>
            <w:pict>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>
                            I dont need this too
                        </w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:pict>
        </w:r>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 text that i need to retrieve...
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Here, I want to retrieve `<w:r><w:t>` value and that `<w:r>` should not contain child `<w:pict>` inside it. So, as per my above XML Document I want to generate the following output:

```
<paragraph>This is the text that i need to retrieve...</paragraph>
```

and this is my XSLT snippet (please tell me what changes does this XSLT require to get above format):

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::w:p[//w:r/w:t[not(ancestor::w:pict)]]">

        <Paragraph>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:t[not(ancestor::w:pict)]" />
        </Paragraph>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

but it is not working...

Please guide me to get out of this issue.

Comment: The text "I dont need this" is contained within a `<w:r><w:t>`, and the `<w:r>` does not contain the child `<w:pict>`. Can you clarify your requirements a bit more, please? It sounds like you need to check for ancestor elements, not child elements.

Comment: @TimC : yes tim.I want to get the <w:t> value whose ancestor not equal to <w:pict>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, if your current node is `/w:document/w:body/w:p` you can retrive all your desired nodes with:

```
w:r/w:t
```

However, if you need to retrive `w:r/w:t` on any level but with out `w:pict` as ancestor, you could use the `ancestor` axis as such:

```
.//w:r/w:t[not(ancestor::w:pict)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are processing this in classic XSLT fashion using top-down recursive descent with xsl:apply-templates, then the way to exclude a w:r that has a w:pict child is like this:

```
<xsl:template match="w:r[w:pict]"/>
```

I seem to remember coming across a case where I wanted to exclude a w:r if its only child element was a w:pict. In that case the solution would be

```
<xsl:template match="w:r[w:pict and count(*)=1]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filtering to retrieve all `w:r` nodes which do not have `w:pict` element

```
<xs:for-each select="//w:r[count(w:pict) = 0]">
    <xsl:value-of select="w:paragraph" />
</xsl:for-each>
```